# Firebase null object reference "long java.lang.Long.longValue()"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an app that has different user levels (e.g admin, general user). Depending on the level of the user, a different activity will be launched. 1 is admin and 2 is a general user. The `AdminMenuActivity` launches by the `MenuActivity` won't.
The error I'm getting is as follows.

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference at com.example.login.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:63)`

I've been working on this for the past few days and I can't solve the problem. The code and database are as follows.

Code

```
public void selectUser(){

    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                if (dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(Long.class) == 1) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , AdminMenuActivity.class));
                }
                else if (dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(Long.class) == 2) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , MenuActivity.class));
                }



        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();


        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

}
```

**Updated** Database

```js
{     "Users" : {
    "H7BKqKwLGTP0qTlL1p2JqFezjWu2" : {
      "email" : "hello@hotmail.com",
      "preference" : "rugby",
      "role" : 2
    },
    "WSBNdlu7ngbyMo2jILR2qE1ZUR32" : {
      "email" : "1234@gmail.com",
      "preference" : "rugby",
      "role" : 1
    }
  },
  "roles" : {
    "uid1" : "admin",
    "uid2" : "general"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you go to in your code, line 61 in the java class MainActivity. Where reference is being called there apparently is null. That is your issue. I think you've asked the question with too much code and information and perhaps even missed the relevant code. So it would probably also be good for yourself to check how to ask questions here on Stackoverflow as some people are ruthless.

Comment: Please show us a more detailed database structure, including the `Users` node. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: ruthless aggression @GamingFelix

Comment: @PeterHaddad ha, I remember my first question ever being bombarded with downvotes. Just trying to give helpful advice :)

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo I've updated the post with the whole database structure.

Comment: At which particular line of code does this error occur?

Comment: @AlexMamo The code runs perfectly when the uid is 1 but when the uid is 2 it crashes at 
               `if (dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(Long.class) == 1) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , AdminMenuActivity.class));
                }`

Comment: @Mark_rath What do you mean through "The code runs perfectly when the uid is 1 but when the uid is 2 it crashes". About which uid are you taking about?

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for all your help but I have got the problem sorted now.

Comment: @Mark_rath how did you solve the problem? I also facing the same problem,Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getValue(Long.class)` is returning null, which means there is no data at the location of the database that you're looking for.  You're going to have to check for this case and decide what to do when your query doesn't find what you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the help.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and accept answers that you found helpful.